# Kubernetes access Persistance volume mount externally

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-volume

I have setup kubernetes Cluster and mounted volume mount as gcePersistentDisk in Google Cloud, It claims and mount successfully in Pods.
But i want to access this volume externally so that i can write it through git/ssh or manual. As disk is Already used and mounted i cannot access it.
How to write files through externally?

Answer (score 0):

[gcePersistentDisk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/) is a network-based disk, and provisioned volumes can only be used by GCE
instances in the same project and zone.

The fact is that this kind of resource supports **readWriteOnce** and **ReadOnlyMany**. 
You can use a GCE persistent storage to share data as read-only between multiple pods in the 
same zone.

Back to your question: **you can write on this volume only from one pod**. No other pods can
use it as write storage - neither external nor from the same project.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    app: php
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: php:7.1-apache
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: php
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: php
          volumeMounts:
            - name: php-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/www
      volumes:
        - name: php-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: php-phantomjs-disk
            fsType: ext4
```